# DateTime to BCD representation

Tags: c#, datetime

How do I convert DateTime(yyyyMMddhhmm) to a packed bcd (size 6) representation on c# ?

```
using System;

namespace Exercise
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte res = to_bcd(12);
        }

        private static byte to_bcd(int n)
        {
            // extract each digit from the input number n
            byte d1 = Convert.ToByte(n/10);
            byte d2 = Convert.ToByte(n%10);
            // combine the decimal digits into a BCD number
            return Convert.ToByte((d1 << 4) | d2);
        }
    }
}
```

The result you get on res variable is 18.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

What you get is correct 18==12(Hex) as you passed to to_bcd.

```
static byte[] ToBCD(DateTime d)
{
    List<byte> bytes = new List<byte>();
    string s = d.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm");
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i+=2 )
    {
        bytes.Add((byte)((s[i] - '0') << 4 | (s[i+1] - '0')));
    }
    return bytes.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: @TzvikaPika, what do we do on SO when we like an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I'll give a short example to demonstrate the idea. You can extend this solution to your whole date format input.

The BCD format encapsulates exactly two decimal digits into one 8-bit number. For example, the representation of `92` would be, in binary:

```
1001 0010
```

or `0x92` in hex. This happens to be `146` when converted to decimal.

The code to do this would need to shift the first digit left by 4 bits and then combine with the second digit. So:

```
byte to_bcd(int n)
{
    // extract each digit from the input number n
    byte d1 = n / 10;
    byte d2 = n % 10;
    // combine the decimal digits into a BCD number
    return (d1 << 4) | d2;
}
```

Comment: Hi Greg and thanks for the quick response, but i didn't really get it.
I do as you suggest for int = 12 (full example on the first message):

The result you get on res variable is 18.

I expected to a 1 byte representation here.  
In addition, what should be done with the long DateTime (yyyyMMddhhmm) ?  Should I convert it to int64 representation and the split it into 6 integers with size of 2 ?


Thanks!

Comment: Your calculation is correct. The number `18` in decimal is `0x12` in hex, which is also the BCD representation of `12` decimal.